# no ManiActivty.java, acticity_main.xml, nor R.java ( when creating new android application project )

Tags: java, android, eclipse, r.java-file

When I tried to create a new android application project, it didn't create ManiActivty.java, acticity_main.xml, nor R.java (there's only BuildConfig.java on the gen package)
and the AndroidManifest is like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8mIR.png

I've tried almost everything (checked that the Android Private Libraries and Android Dependencies in the java build path are checked, deleted gen and cleaned the project, restarting eclipse, reinstalling eclipse, tried with different Minimum Required SDK(with or without appcompat_v7) , but NONE of these were useful...

My ADT version is updated.

On the SDK manager I installed:

```
Android SDK tools Rev. 24
Android SDK Platform-tools Rev. 21
Android SDK Build-tools Rev. 21.1.1
Android 4.0 (API 14)
Android Support Repository Rev. 9
Android Support Library Rev.21.0.2 (also tried to reinstall it 2 times)
Google Repository Rev. 14
Google USB Driver Rev. 11
```

Windows 7 (64-bit)

and I have the latest version of java, and eclipse version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)

please help.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that ADT is no longer officially updated. Instead of solving this particular problem, I would suggest switching to Android Studio (which is now version 1.0) for stability and support.

And to be less official - leave ADT alone, it is outdated and will cause you more problems in the future. As an experienced developer I strongly encourage you to switch to Android Studio, you will not regret. Also, you may still use your existing SDK files with Studio, you won't have to download all this again :-)